# Parent background over child's

Tags: css, html

I was wondering maybe there is any way I can do this with CSS.

I have the parent div, and child one. The child is always going to have a background-color, and I want to switch additional class in data loading case. So when data is loading, parent div will have the background image and color (probably rgba with transparency).
The reason I want to do this with parent is I don't know the exact number of childen, or resulting height, so loading overlay div seems not to be a good idea...

http://jsfiddle.net/3Xpnx/15/ here is fiddle, where it can be seen that child's background is over parents

```
.parent{
background: url('http://www.securenet.com/sites/default/files/spinner.gif') no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / contain #FFF;
z-index:10000;
position:relative;
```

}

```
.child{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: rgba(0,250,250,.7);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a pseudo element which would have to be removed once the loading has finished (but that's another issue). Here I used a hover to show it on and off.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Xpnx/19/)

**HTML**

some content

**CSS**

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}
.parent:after {
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    background: url('http://www.securenet.com/sites/default/files/spinner.gif') no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / contain #FFF;
}

/* temp hover state for demo purposes*/

.parent:hover:after {
    display:none;
}

.child {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 250, 250, .7);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to avoid absolute positioning, however, as I can see, this is impossible

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using absolute positioning **when** required for specific effects. Using it for general layout though...yes, avoid like the plague.